# Setting html using jQuery on li element results in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Here is jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/howg59sg/5/

```
<div id='test1'>
    <ul>
        <li id="li1" friendName="foo">test 1</li>
        <li id="li2" friendName="bar">test 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

function myclick() {
    alert("clicked");
    var elemId = "#li1";
    var elemCollection = jQuery(elemId);
    alert("len = " + elemCollection.length);
    if (elemCollection.length) {
        var selectedElem = elemCollection[0];
        alert("id of the element to work on " + selectedElem.attributes["id"].value);
        var stringToReplaceWith = "testing";
        alert("friendname = " + selectedElem.attributes["friendname"].value);
        //alert("html value of selected elem = " + selectedElem.html());

        selectedElem.html(stringToReplaceWith);
    } else {
        alert("none");
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to update the html content of a li element using jQuery. This results in following error:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I am able to get attributes on this li element but html() setter fails. Even getter fails as well which i have commented out in the code for now...

Does anyone know, What might be wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, it's much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `selectedElem` is not a jQuery object.

```
var selectedElem = elemCollection[0];  <-- gets the DOM node
selectedElem.html(stringToReplaceWith);  <-- you treat it as a jQuery object
```

either use `.eq(0`) to get the element as jQuery instead of bracket notation and use `.attr()` to read the attributes Or wrap it with `jQuery()` or use `innerHTML`

Comment: That solved the problem. I didn't know that distinction. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely with this line:

```
var selectedElem = elemCollection[0];
```

That will give you a regular DOM element object instead of a jQuery object. DOM elements don't have the `html()` function like jQuery objects do. You can replace the whole function with just these lines of code:

```
function myclick(){
  jQuery('#li1').html('testing');
}
```

Comment: yeah, i didn't know that difference. Thanks. I can't though do what you suggest because in my app, it is possible that this element may not be present on the page. (it will be there on only one page). So I have to check the collection length. But again, now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The following line returns a native DOM Html element:

```
elemCollection[0];
```

If you want the first item in a collection as a jQuery element use [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
elemCollection.first();
```